# How to list Enum's members

Tags: vb.net, enums

How to list Enum's members in code? I have the following Enum:

```
Public Enum TestEnum As int32
    First = 0
    Second = 2
    Third = 4
    Fourth = 6
End Enum
```

And I try to list all members of TestEnum via the following code but it failed:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Enum1 As TestEnum

        Dim Members() As String

        Members = System.Enum.GetNames(CType(Enum1, System.Enum))


    End Sub
End Class
```

So, my question is: How to list members of an Enum?

**Update**: The solution is:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Members() As String
        Members = System.Enum.GetNames(GetType(TestEnum))

        MessageBox.Show(Join(Members, Chr(13) & Chr(10)))

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 28):

You can simply iterate through all values like this:

```
Public Enum TestEnum As int32
    First = 0
    Second = 2
    Third = 4
    Fourth = 6
End Enum

For Each tstEnum As TestEnum In System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(TestEnum))

    Response.Write(
        String.Format("Name: {0}  Value: {1}", 
            tstEnum.ToString, 
            CInt(tstEnum).ToString
        )
    )

Next
```

Answer (score 19):

You need to pass a type, not a value, to the method.

```
Members = System.Enum.GetNames(GetType(TestEnum))
```

If you have an instance of your enum you can also use

```
Members = System.Enum.GetNames(Enum1.GetType())
```

Though I would recommend the first approach if you know the type you want.

Answer (score 10):

I have used [George Filippakos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24475821/6783663) since I wanted to know how to iterate through `Enum` values.

I also found out that you can do it using [Type.GetEnumValues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getenumvalues(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) which has been available since `.NET Framework 4.0`.

Here's the two ways you can use to iterate through `Enum` Values:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        For Each tstEnum As TestEnum In System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(TestEnum))
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {tstEnum.ToString}, Value: {CType(tstEnum, Integer)}")
        Next

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine)

        For Each tstEnum As TestEnum In GetType(TestEnum).GetEnumValues
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {tstEnum.ToString}, Value: {CType(tstEnum, Integer)}")
        Next

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Public Enum TestEnum
        First = 1
        Second = 2
        Third = 3
    End Enum
End Module
```

---

Output:

```
Name: First, Value: 1
Name: Second, Value: 2
Name: Third, Value: 3

Name: First, Value: 1
Name: Second, Value: 2
Name: Third, Value: 3
```

Answer (score 8):

Have you looked at [Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) ?

Edit: To clarify, yes you need to pass a Type not an instance of the enum to either method.

```
Enum.GetNames(GetType(TestEnum))
```

Comment: I just test it, it failed too. Visual Studio 2010 say: "Value type cannot converted to system.type"

Comment: See my answer. You need to pass a type, not a value, to both GetNames and GetValues.

Comment: It needs to be `System.Enum.GetNames` or `[Enum].GetNames`.